# Hangman Python two instances of the same character

Tags: python

```
elif guess in word:
    already_guessed.extend([guess])
    index = word.find(guess)
    word = word[:index] + "_" + word [index +1:]
    display = display[:index] + guess + display[index +1:]
    print (display + "\n")
```

Word to guess is queen, if i guess e it will not fill both instances of e. How would you fix this?

Comment: Inefficient, but simple: use a loop to repeat finding the character, using until all occurences are found

Answer (score 0):

Extending zvone's answer:

```
elif guess in word:
    already_guessed.extend([guess])
    for index in range(len(word)):
        if word[index] == guess:
            word = word[:index] + "_" + word [index +1:]
            display = display[:index] + guess + display[index +1:]
    print (display + "\n")
```